# How to deduce the mode associated with a call option value?

Tags: options

Option value being expressed:

$$OV=e^{-rT}E[max(V-K,0)] \tag{1}$$

Where $V$ is the price of the underlying security, $K$ is the strike price, and $r,T$ are discount rate and time to exercise date, as usual.

In the "Key Result" on pg. 352 of [this edition](http://accountingpdf.com/download/?file=6507) of Hull's book, Hull shows how the Black Scholes Merton formula for call option pricing results from $(1)$ if $V$ is lognormally distributed.

My question is: How can I deduce the mode (i.e., the most likely value, as opposed to the expected value) of the distribution implicit in $(1)$?

Answer (score 1):

If the question is about the underlying, Wikipedia has the answer. If the log of a variable is normal $N(\mu,\sigma)$ then the variable itself is lognormal with mode at $e^{\mu-\sigma^2}$ and mean at $e^{\mu+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2}$. The Median (or 50% point) is at $e^\mu$. [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Arithmetic_moments) that I find very useful in working with option maths.

If the question is about the call option, we can analyze it in terms of different cases depending how high the strike price is. I'll assume $r=0$ for simplicity.

If $K < e^{\mu-\sigma^2}$ then the cutoff is at a point on the curve where the density is still increasing (i.e. we are to the left of the mode). In this case the most likely value for the option is the excess of the mode over the strike: $e^{\mu-\sigma^2}-K$

In the opposite case, the density for the stock declines monotonically to the right of K. So the most likely value for the stock is K, and after subtracting K we are left with a most likely option value of 0.

But TBH I am not sure why anyone cares what the most likely case is. It makes more sense to analyze the situation based on the expectation.

Comment: But that would just be the mode of the underlying security $V$.

Comment: Whereas I'm asking for the mode of $max(V-K,0)$.